# ASP.NET doesn't redirect to admin page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

When I enter username and password in login page in asp.net and after check user doesn't get redirected to admin page.

This is my code:

```
 if (Page.IsValid)
 {
        if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/ManagePage/Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            if (CheckLogin(UserName.Text.Trim(), Password.Text.Trim()) == true)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text.Trim(), false);

                if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName.Text.Trim())[0] == "Admin")
                {
                    Session["CounterLogin"] = 0;
                    Response.Redirect("~/ManagePage/Default.aspx");
                }
                else if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName.Text)[0] == "User")
                {
                    Session["CounterLogin"] = 0;
                    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Please Check UserName And Password";
            }
        }
}
```

I'm using this code in other project that works, but in my new project it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try useing FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie for do login:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text.Trim(), false);
```

and check enable FormsAuthentication in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" >
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: it's return to login page again